# Проблемы с получением KEY HASH при интеграции с facebook

Tags: android, facebooksdk

Пытаюсь интегрировать проект с Facebook. Нашел этот мануал [тыц](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2015/01/facebook-sdk-android.html)

на этапе получения KEY HASH  возникает проблема: Если использовать код для вставки в активити - срабатывает исключение,а при получении через командную  строку

ввожу это `exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Kirill.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64`

и вижу это, вместо ключа [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896304/openssl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) на en-So

В моем случае нужно было скачать OpenSSL, прописать переменную среды Path - C:\openssl и прописать команду

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```